# eliminate first numeric from string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the data in column like this **12 address**, i want to eliminate numeric with address how can i do to achieve the result **Address**. Here can be any other string also not only address.

Query:

```
SELECT Address FROM TABLE
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want this for MySQL or SQL Server? Also, tell us more about the format. Is the number always delimited by a space, etc.

Comment: @cularis: i want in sql server and yes number always delimited by a space.

Comment: @Sami: I'm removing the `mysql` tag as irrelevant then. Please be more careful when picking tags for your questions.

Comment: @andriy: ok thanks but @cularis answer has been removed also that was more easy to understand answer.

Comment: @Sami: It was removed before I removed the tag. @cularis must have removed it immediately after seeing your response to him/her.

Comment: @Sami: Possibly @niktrs's answer is the same. My answer is different because it doesn't assume there's always a space after the number. (I answered before seeing your response to @cularis.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Address, FirstPos, 2147483647)), '') AS Address
FROM (
  SELECT
    Address,
    NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Address), 0) AS FirstPos
  FROM atable
) s
```

Comment: @niktrs: what is 2147483647? i am sorry i am unable to understand because i am not much good in sql.

Comment: This is the maximum length of varchar (2^31-1 bytes). You can use this value as the end of the substring since no varchar column will be greater than that, or the columns length value

Comment: @Sami: `2147483647` is just a very big number (the largest `int` value, actually) to guarantee that you'll get all the characters up to the end of `Address`. I could instead calculate the necessary length precisely, like @niktrs did, i.e. `LEN(Address) - FirstPos + 1`. But the length would later be checked internally anyway, so putting a fairly big number makes it a tiny bit faster.

Comment: i have changed it according to my requirement and it gives me error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'." AS with FirstPos. This is my query: SELECT COALESCE(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(PropertyName, FirstPos, 2147483647)), '') AS PropertyName
FROM (  SELECT PropertyName, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PropertyName) AS FirstPos, 0)
  FROM [Property]
). There is the case that there cannot be numeric in start.

Comment: @Sami: It was my silly mistake, sorry. Basically, `AS FirstPos` should be slightly relocated, like in my updated answer.

Comment: @andriy: this is working fine. thanks. What if i have to select more columns from this table?

Comment: @Sami: Add them both to the subselect and to the outer select. (Yes, you are thus duplicating the column list partly, but personally I don't see any problem with that.)

Comment: @Andriy: Should i need to add joins with other tables also in inner and outer select?

Comment: @Sami: No. Join other tables either in the subselect or in the outer select. The latter is probably better, particularly when you need to pull columns from other tables too, because if you joined the tables in the inner select, you'd have to repeat in the outer select the columns being pulled from the joined tables. Just make sure your outer select has all the necessary columns for joining.

Comment: @Andriy: Really thanks, i have got the required functionality by adding the result of this into temp table and then using inner join with other tables. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(address, CHARINDEX(' ',address)+1,field_len)
FROM table
```

Explained

Syntax: SUBSTRING(fieldname, start_position, end_position)

In your case

```
SUBSTRING( 
address -- your field name
, CHARINDEX(' ',address)+1 -- find the space char
, field_len -- get all the rest of the string
)
```

Comment: What if some records has no numeric in the start?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT(Address,LEN(Address) - CHARINDEX (' ', Address) + 1) FROM tbl
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: This also works fine and the above answered post also works as well. Thanks.

Comment: I often prefer `RIGHT` to `SUBSTRING` where possible. But in SQL Server `RIGHT` should be used with care. For example, if `Address` contained trailing spaces, `LEN` would return incorrect length and consequently `RIGHT` would return incorrect string.